# Compute the Jacobi bracket

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

$R(x,y,z)=(x,y,z)$ and $\Theta(x,y,z)=(xz,yz,-(x^2+y^2))$

Show $[R,\Theta]=\Theta$

$[R,\Theta]=(R\cdot\nabla)\Theta-(\Theta\cdot\nabla)R$

$[R,\Theta]=(\frac{d}{dx}x+\frac{d}{dy}y+\frac{d}{dz}z)(xz,yz,-(x^2+y^2))-(\frac{d}{dx}xz+\frac{d}{dy}yz-\frac{d}{dz}(x^2+y^2)(x,y,z)$

$=((\frac{d}{dx}x+\frac{d}{dy}y+\frac{d}{dz}z)(xz),(\frac{d}{dx}x+\frac{d}{dy}y+\frac{d}{dz}z)(yz),(\frac{d}{dx}x+\frac{d}{dy}y+\frac{d}{dz}z)(-(x^2+y^2)))-((\frac{d}{dx}xz+\frac{d}{dy}yz-\frac{d}{dz}(x^2+y^2))x,(\frac{d}{dx}xz+\frac{d}{dy}yz-\frac{d}{dz}(x^2+y^2))y,(\frac{d}{dx}xz+\frac{d}{dy}yz-\frac{d}{dz}(x^2+y^2))z)$

$=(5xz,5yz,-5(x^2+y^2))-(3xz,3yz,2z^2-x^2-y^2)$

$=(2xz,2yz,-4x^2-4y^2-2z^2)\neq(xz,yz,-(x^2+y^2))$

Have tried this computation many times and keep getting the same wrong answer, must have a problem with my method, please help, it would be greatly appreciated. Not a hard computation, just long.

If you arrive at $(R\cdot\nabla)\Theta-(\Theta\cdot\nabla)R=\Theta$, please post working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key point is that $R\cdot\nabla\ne \nabla\cdot R$, in your notation. You should have $x\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}+\dots$ and similarly for the other term.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, this problem has been bothering me for a while. Will give it another go.

Comment: Got it thanks, I wouldn't have been able to compute the Jacobi bracket without this help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ted Shifrin's post, I have found the mistakes I was making. Here is the correct working:

$R(x,y,z)=(x,y,z)$, $\Theta(x,y,z)=(xz,yz,-(x^2+y^2))$

$[R,\Theta]=(R\cdot\nabla)\Theta-(\Theta\cdot\nabla)R$

$[R,\Theta]=(x\frac{d}{dx}+y\frac{d}{dy}y+z\frac{d}{dz})(xz,yz,-(x^2+y^2))-((xz\frac{d}{dx}+yz\frac{d}{dy}-(x^2+y^2)\frac{d}{dz})(x,y,z))$

$=((x\frac{d}{dx}+y\frac{d}{dy}+z\frac{d}{dz})(xz),(x\frac{d}{dx}+y\frac{d}{dy}+z\frac{d}{dz})(yz),(x\frac{d}{dx}+y\frac{d}{dy}+z\frac{d}{dz})(-(x^2+y^2)))-((xz\frac{d}{dx}+yz\frac{d}{dy}-(x^2+y^2)\frac{d}{dz})x,(xz\frac{d}{dx}+yz\frac{d}{dy}-(x^2+y^2)\frac{d}{dz})y,(xz\frac{d}{dx}+yz\frac{d}{dy}-(x^2+y^2)\frac{d}{dz})z)$

$=(xz+xz,yz+yz,-2x^2-2y^2)-(xz,yz,-(x^2+y^2))$

$=2\Theta-\Theta=\Theta$